# What is the meaning of 見たいない？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, slang

Why use 見たいない instead of 見たくない? Does it infer a different meaning? I found it in this sentence: 一定の点数に見たいない者は２次試験を受けることができない.

Comment: It must be [満]{み}たない instead of [見]{み}たいない.

Comment: @mackygoo unfortunately not, it's on this page: https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/67786/ on the tenth paragraph.

Comment: It would be a typo.

Comment: I agree, this is a typo for 満たない.